# How can I count the amount of spaces at the start of a string in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

How can I count the amount of spaces at the start of a string in Perl?

I now have:

```
  $temp = rtrim($line[0]);
  $count = ($temp =~ tr/^ //);
```

But that gives me the count of all spaces.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$str =~ /^(\s*)/;
my $count = length( $1 );
```

If you just want actual spaces (instead of whitespace), then that would be:

```
$str =~ /^( *)/;
```

**Edit:** The reason why `tr` doesn't work is it's not a regular expression operator. What you're doing with `$count = ( $temp =~ tr/^ // );` is replacing all instances of `^` and  with itself (see comment below by cjm), then counting up how many replacements you've done. `tr` doesn't see `^` as "hey this is the beginning of the string pseudo-character" it sees it as "hey this is a `^`".

Comment: `tr` doesn't delete characters unless you use the `/d` modifier.  The original code was actually replacing `^` and space with `^` and space (if the REPLACEMENTLIST is empty, the SEARCHLIST is replicated(http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#tr%2fSEARCHLIST%2fREPLACEMENTLIST%2fcds).)

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for the correction. I've edited my post to reflect reality.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the offset of a match using [`@-`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%40-).  If you search for a non-whitespace character, this will be the number of whitespace characters at the start of the string:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

for my $s ("foo bar", " foo bar", "  foo bar", "  ") {
        my $count = $s =~ /\S/ ? $-[0] : length $s;
        print "'$s' has $count whitespace characters at its start\n";
}
```

Or, even better, use [`@+`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%40+) to find the end of the whitespace:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

for my $s ("foo bar", " foo bar", "  foo bar", "  ") {
    $s =~ /^\s*/;
    print "$+[0] '$s'\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script that does this for every line of stdin.  The relevant snippet of code is the first in the body of the loop.

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl

  while ($x = <>) {
    $s = length(($x =~ m/^( +)/)[0]);
    print $s, ":", $x, "\n";
  }
```

Comment: oops.  looks like concurrent similar answers.

Answer (score 1):

`tr///` is not a regex operator. However, you can use `s///`:

```
use strict; use warnings;

my $t = (my $s = " \t\n  sdklsdjfkl");
my $n = 0;

++$n while $s =~ s{^\s}{};
print "$n \\s characters were removed from \$s\n";

$n = ( $t =~ s{^(\s*)}{} ) && length $1;
print "$n \\s characters were removed from \$t\n";
```

Comment: That will be destructive on the original string, so make sure to assign to a separate variable if you want to retrieve the original value later!

Answer (score 1):

Since the regexp matcher returns the parenthesed matches when called in a list context, CanSpice's answer can be written in a single statement:

```
$count = length( ($line[0] =~ /^( *)/)[0] );
```

Answer (score 1):

This prints amount of white space

```
echo "   hello" |perl -lane 's/^(\s+)(.*)+$/length($1)/e; print'
```

3

Comment: No need to substitute, just match.